# can't access pdo connection in child class

Tags: php, pdo

I am having a problem making a pdo connection accessible over extended classes e.g :

```
class Model {

public $connection;

public function __construct(PDO $connection = null)
{
    global $config;
    $this->connection = $connection;
    if ($this->connection === null) {
        $this->connection = new PDO(
        'mysql:host='.$config['db_host'].';dbname='.$config['db_name'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password']);
        $this->connection->setAttribute(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
            PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
    }
}
```

And another class extending model

```
class User extends Model { 
    public function someFunction(){
        // how can I access the pdo connection in the parent constructer here?
    }
}
```

Thats the crux of the issue I wan't to access the parent connection created in the constructor in child classes, guidance much appreciated.

Comment: it is wrong to create connections in model object, anyway to access parent's property you can simple use `$this->connection...` in child

Comment: Since `User extends Model`, you can just access `$this->connection`.

Answer (score 0):

As constructors are not implicitly called in PHP, you need to add some lines at least, and afterwards just use `$this`:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function __construct(PDO $connection = null) {
         parent::__construct($connection);
    }

    public function someFunction(){
         // access the pdo connection in the parent here:
         $this->connection->.....

    }
}
```

Comment: if I do somehting like this

static function someFunction(){
         // access the pdo connection in the parent here:
         var_dump($this->connection)

    }

it returns an error

Using $this when not in object context

Comment: It was because my function someFunction was declared as static